# How to find this probability?

Tags: probability

> In a company, it's known that $45 \%$ of the employees have a graduate (university), a half are not graduate and make less than $\$1500$ per month.Those who are graduate, $\frac{2}{9}$ make less than $\$1500$

What is the probability of one employee not be graduate, knowing that makes more or equal than $\$1500$?

Fist I set two events:

- $A$ - "To be graduate"
- $B$ - "To make less than $\$1500$"

I know that the question is about $P(\bar{A}|\bar{B})$.From the introdution I know that:

$P(A)=0{,}45$

$P(\bar{A}\cap B)=0{,}5$

$P(B|A)=\frac{2}{9}$

But I don't know how to find the probability asked.Can you explain me how to do it?

Comment: probability-theory and set-theory tags are for more advanced topics. axiom-of-choice is not applicable here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a problem like this, a straightforward approach is to enumerate the possibilities:

$$\begin{aligned}
P(A \cap B) &= 0.10 \\
P(A \cap \bar B) &= 0.35 \\
P(\bar A \cap B) &= 0.50 \\
P(\bar A \cap \bar B) &= 0.05 \\
\end{aligned}$$

Now we can calculate:

$$P(\bar A \,|\, \bar B)
 = \frac{P(\bar A \cap \bar B)}{P(\bar B)}
 = \frac{P(\bar A \cap \bar B)}{P(\bar A \cap \bar B) + P(A \cap \bar B)}
 = \frac{0.05}{0.05 + 0.35} = \frac{1}{8} = 12.5\%
$$

---

Ps. How did I calculate the four base probabilities above?  Well...

- $P(\bar A \cap B)$ we already know
- $P(\bar A \cap \bar B) = 1 - P(A) - P(\bar A \cap B)$
- $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \; P(B|A)$
- and $P(A \cap \bar B)$ is what's left over.

Comment: I get the answer as $\frac{1}{8}$. Ah, I see, you have put 0.50 instead of 0.35.

Comment: Ah, great. I was about to ask "how did you calculate the four possibilities".

Comment: @Aryabhata: Oops, well spotted!  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Ilmari Karonen.I'have to review the theme.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(\bar A \,|\, \bar B)
 = \frac{P(\bar A \cap \bar B)}{P(\bar B)}$$
 $$=  \tag{1}\frac{1-P( A \cup B)}{1-P( B) }$$
 $$= \frac{0.05}{1-0.6} = \frac{1}{8} $$

$(1)$:

- $P(A \cap B)= P(B|A)P(A)=\frac{2}{9} \cdot 0.45=0.1$
- $P(\bar A \cap \bar B) = 1 - P(A) - P(\bar A \cap B)=1-0.45-0.5=0.05$

Then  we have $P(B)$ from $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$